# PHP Facebook API: get event details in one go

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to retrieve all events of a feed and gather the event details, too. Like this, I am querying the feed:

```
    // instantiate
    $facebook = new Facebook($config);

    $pagefeed = $facebook->api("/" . $pageid . "/feed");

    foreach($pagefeed['data'] as $post) {

            // check if post type is a link
            if ($post['type'] == 'event') {
                // call API to retrieve the event details
            }
    }
```

As you can see, I need to send one request for each event. Can I avoid this like using the "expand" command in oData?

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Allright, I figured it out myself. The approach I was using so far was outdated. When using the version 4x of the API it works like this:

```
    // init app with app id and secret
    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( FB_APP_ID, FB_SECRET);

    // If you're making app-level requests:
    $session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();

    // To validate the session:
    try {
        $session->validate();
    } catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
        // Session not valid, Graph API returned an exception with the reason.
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        // Graph API returned info, but it may mismatch the current app or have expired.
    }

    try {
        $request = new FacebookRequest(
            $session,
            'GET',
            // get all events of a Page, ?fields= let you choose which fields you want the Graph to return
            '/' . FB_ID . '/events?fields=id,end_time,cover,description,is_date_only,location,name,start_time&since='
                . strtotime('-1 year') . '&until=' . strtotime('+1 year')
                . '&limit=10&locale=de_DE&date_format=d. M, y  H:m'
        );
        $response = $request->execute();
        $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
        // handle the result -> returns an indexed array without key
        $objectData = $graphObject['data'];
```

Pretty simple if you know how to do it...    ;-)

Hope this helps someone else struggeling, too.